# Centering a DIV Table Beneath another Fixed Table

Tags: css, html

So I have a div table set up with this CSS, as below, so that it is centered and fixed at the top of the page. I can set up another div and center it but I am having trouble getting the DIV to be below the top one. Any advice?

This is the css for the top DIV:

> 

```
.fixedtop
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -400px;
    background-image: url(bannerlogo.jpg);
    width:800px;
    height: 414;
}
```

This is the most recent css that I have tested:

> 

```
.fixedcenter
{
        position:center;
    margin-top: 414px;
    width:800px;
    height: 414px;
}
```

I've also tried to use padding and messing with margins for centering. All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There's no `position:center` in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.fixedtop
{
    margin-left: auto;  
    margin-right: auto; 
    border: 1px solid black; /* I only added the borders so that I could*/
                             /* see what was happening more easily.*/
    background-image: url(bannerlogo.jpg); 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 414px;
}

.fixedcenter
{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 414px;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: 2 divs]

Answer (score 0):

If you use "position", the correct values are: static, relative and absolute. If the height of your divs will not vary, then you can use position:absolute and specify the position using "top"

Example: You can do something like this for the second element:

`.fixedcenter2
{
position:absolute;
margin-top: 414px;
width:800px;
height: 414px;
top: 424px //It will be positioned 20px below the first.

}`

Comment: I can send you a good tutorial on CSS, I'm sure you'll find what you're looking for. Can you give me your mail?